# Install packages failed: Error occurred when installing package beautifulsoup4?

Tags: python, pycharm, package

Why can't I install packages in my PyCharm?I remember that i can install some packages a couple of days ago...

Detail:

```
The error output of the command:
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "E:\PyCharm 3.4.1\helpers\packaging_tool.py", line 125, in main
   retcode = do_install(pkgs)
 File "E:\PyCharm 3.4.1\helpers\packaging_tool.py", line 56, in do_install
   import pip
 File "E:\python\lib\site-packages\pip\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
   import logging
 File "E:\python\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
   import sys, os, time, cStringIO, traceback, warnings, weakref, collections
 File "E:\python\lib\collections\__init__.py", line 50
   self, *args = args
         ^
 SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 0):

This is likely because you're using a very old version of PyCharm that was buggy. You're currently using 3.4.1 (as shown in your error log), when you should actually be using 4.5.3.